# findByIdAndUpdate not updating document on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to create an Api that updates my MongoDB before sending a password reset email to the user using nodemailer. Everything works fine except the database update for some reason. I am using findByIdAndUpdate to do the update.
My api starts with

```
    router.put('/forgot',[auth, [check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail()]],async (req, res) => {
const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
}
const { email } = req.body;
try {
  let user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      errors: [
        {
          msg:
            'That email addrss is not recognized. Please try again or register for a new account ',
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  var email_token = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');

  const payload = {
    id: user.id,
    resetPasswordToken: email_token,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date.now() + 3600000,
  };

  user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    user.id,
    { $set: payload },
    { new: true }
  );
  console.log(user);
  res.json(user);
```

Comment: What does the `console.log(user)` at the end output?

Comment: we need to see the User Model

Comment: Than you Joe and Mohammed,
Well from Mohammed question i realized i did not define 
resetPasswordToken and  resetPasswordExpires in the User Model. As soon as i did that every thing worked as magic. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Joe and Mohammed, Well from Mohammed question i realized i did not define resetPasswordToken and resetPasswordExpires in the User Model. As soon as i did that every thing worked as magic. Thank you so much!